# Is there any way to make this query faster?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to retrieve a list of schedules that occur between a start and end date. I have a parent record and list of child records for every schedule.

```
Schedule
  Id

ScheduleDates
  ScheduleId
  Start
  End
```

The end goal is to be able to show a grouped list of dates. So if I have multiple schedules that start on the same day and end on the same day, they should be grouped together.

```
Jan 10 - 15
  - Schedule 1
  - Schedule 2
Jan 10 - 20
  - Schedule 3
  - Schedule 4
Feb 1 - 3
  - Schedule 5
```

The first query looks something like this:

```
var schedules = from schedule in _db.Schedules
                join date in _db.ScheduleDates on schedule.Id equals date.ScheduleId
                // join a bunch of other tables
                // bunch of where queries
                && date.Start >= startDate
                && date.Start <= endDate
                select schedule;
```

This returns the records I want, my problem is when I need to group the records together by the earliest and latest child records. The rest don't matter.

Trying to add the following works

```
group new {
  //
} by new { 
   Start = schedule.ScheduleDates.Min(x=>x.Start),
   End = schedule.ScheduleDates.Max(x=>x.Start)
}
```

It just doesn't work well. When I have several thousand records it is incredibly slow because it's basically executing a query with the following where clause for every single row:

```
WHERE (((@x1 IS NULL) AND (((
    SELECT MIN([t4].[StartDate])
    FROM [dbo].[ScheduleDate] AS [t4]
    WHERE [t4].[ScheduleDate_ScheduleId] = [t1].[ScheduleId]
    )) IS NULL)) OR ((@x1 IS NOT NULL) AND (((
    SELECT MIN([t5].[StartDate])
    FROM [dbo].[ScheduleDate] AS [t5]
    WHERE [t5].[ScheduleDate_ScheduleId] = [t1].[ScheduleId]
    )) IS NOT NULL) AND (((@x1 IS NULL) AND (((
    SELECT MIN([t6].[StartDate])
    FROM [dbo].[ScheduleDate] AS [t6]
    WHERE [t6].[ScheduleDate_ScheduleId] = [t1].[ScheduleId]
    )) IS NULL)) OR ((@x1 IS NOT NULL) AND (((
    SELECT MIN([t7].[StartDate])
    FROM [dbo].[ScheduleDate] AS [t7]
    WHERE [t7].[ScheduleDate_ScheduleId] = [t1].[ScheduleId]
    )) IS NOT NULL) AND (@x1 = ((
    SELECT MIN([t8].[StartDate])
    FROM [dbo].[ScheduleDate] AS [t8]
    WHERE [t8].[ScheduleDate_ScheduleId] = [t1].[ScheduleId]
    ))))))) AND (((@x2 IS NULL) AND (((
    SELECT MAX([t9].[StartDate])
    FROM [dbo].[ScheduleDate] AS [t9]
    WHERE [t9].[ScheduleDate_ScheduleId] = [t1].[ScheduleId]
    )) IS NULL)) OR ((@x2 IS NOT NULL) AND (((
    SELECT MAX([t10].[StartDate])
    FROM [dbo].[ScheduleDate] AS [t10]
    WHERE [t10].[ScheduleDate_ScheduleId] = [t1].[ScheduleId]
    )) IS NOT NULL) AND (((@x2 IS NULL) AND (((
    SELECT MAX([t11].[StartDate])
    FROM [dbo].[ScheduleDate] AS [t11]
    WHERE [t11].[ScheduleDate_ScheduleId] = [t1].[ScheduleId]
    )) IS NULL)) OR ((@x2 IS NOT NULL) AND (((
    SELECT MAX([t12].[StartDate])
    FROM [dbo].[ScheduleDate] AS [t12]
    WHERE [t12].[ScheduleDate_ScheduleId] = [t1].[ScheduleId]
    )) IS NOT NULL) AND (@x2 = ((
    SELECT MAX([t13].[StartDate])
    FROM [dbo].[ScheduleDate] AS [t13]
    WHERE [t13].[ScheduleDate_ScheduleId] = [t1].[ScheduleId]
    )))))))
```

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to move your logic to C# code - it doesn't have to be in SQL.

So, first query the database for the minimum set of data you will need. Then write some C# to manipulate the data and group it as per your requirements.

SQL is not a general-purpose programming language!

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is, in this case, an abstraction on top of SQL. As with all abstractions it leaks. If you're looking for better performance you might want to drop down to the native SQL and run the query like that. You don't mention if you're using Linq2SQL or Nhibernate or EF or ... but each one has a way of getting down to the raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If this were a SQL statement, I'd do this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT    
    Schedules.Id ScheduleId,
    MIN(ScheduleDates.Date) Date
  FROM
    Schedules INNER JOIN ScheduleDates ON Schedules.Id = ScheduleDates.ScheduleId
  WHERE 
    ScheduleDates.Date > :1
    AND ScheduleDate.Date < :2

    UNION 

  SELECT    
    Schedules.Id ScheduleId,
    MAX(ScheduleDates.Date) Date
  FROM
    Schedules INNER JOIN ScheduleDates ON Schedules.Id = ScheduleDates.ScheduleId
  WHERE 
    ScheduleDates.Date > :1
    AND ScheduleDate.Date < :2
  ) A
  ORDER BY ScheduleId, Date
```

Though I tend to avoid UNIONS and would just select the MIN and MAX together:

```
SELECT  
  Schedules.Id ScheduleId,
  MIN(ScheduleDates.Date) MinDate,
  MAX(ScheduleDates.Date) MaxDate,
FROM
  Schedules INNER JOIN ScheduleDates ON Schedules.Id = ScheduleDates.ScheduleId
WHERE 
  ScheduleDates.Date > :1
  AND ScheduleDate.Date < :2
GROUP BY Schedules.Id
ORDER BY Schedules.Id, ScheduleDates.Date
```

I'm not so up-and-up on LINQ but with this SQL in mind, I'm sure someone can pick up the baton and find the right LINQ to represent this. I hope anyway =)

Comment: One of the problems with LINQ is that you have no control over the SQL created.  You are at the mercy of the provider to produce SQL that works but is not nessesarly the most optimal.  Although it may be possible to get LINQ to generate something simlar, I really doubt it.

Comment: OK, Another "intermediate" might be to create a view with one of these and use LINQ on the view. (For filtering if needed) And thanks for the info Mark =)